# Arranging exercises row-wise on the page

Tags: spacing, exam

I have been using `tabularx` to arrange practice exercises on the page, like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\footer{}{}{}
\parindent=0in
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\section{More Practice With Trig Identities}
Establish each identity.
\begin{questions}
\newlength{\spacer}
\setlength{\spacer}{1in}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ XX }
    \question $\left(\sec\theta+\tan\theta\right)\left(\sec\theta-\tan\theta\right)=1$ 
        & \question $\dfrac{1-\sin\theta}{1+\sin\theta} = \left(\sec\theta-\tan\theta\right)^2 $     \\ [\spacer]
    \question $\tan^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\cot^2\theta\sin^2\theta=1 $ 
        & \question $\sec^4\theta - \sec^2\theta= \tan^4\theta + \tan^2\theta $  \\ [\spacer]
    \question $\sec\theta-\tan\theta=\dfrac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin\theta} $ 
        & \question $3\sin^2\theta+4\cos^2\theta=\cos^2\theta+3 $    \\ [\spacer]
    \question $1-\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = \cos\theta $ 
        &    \question $\cos^2\theta\left(1+\tan^2\theta\right)=1$ \\ [\spacer]
\end{tabularx}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: layout of exercises on page]

I know that this is not what tabular environments were designed for, and it's obviously less than ideal, especially when things have different heights.  But what should I be using instead of `tabular`?

Comment: `tabularx` isn't needed there you just have `XX` so tex sets the teable multiple times and does lots of calculations just to work out the width of X which you know in advance is half \textwidth -2\tabcolsep) so you could just use p{(\textwidth-2\tabcolsep)/2} (calc package), or you could simply use two minipages and no tabular at all. your equations would be better in display mode so \[\] rather than $

Comment: @DavidCarlisle However, using two `minipage`s will change how exercises are numbered (column-wise rather than row-wise, as desired).

Comment: @Jubobs why? two X _is_ two minipages more or less, it is the same thing.

Comment: `p{(\textwidth-4\tabcolsep)/2}` (correction to what I wrote above:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just tried using two `minipage`s: in the output, the first column contains questions 1 to 4 and the second column contains questions 5 to 8. I thing the OP wants to have questions arranged on the page as shown on the screenshot s/he posted.

Comment: Yes, I've done some informal A/B testing, and students do significantly better when exercise sheets are numbered as I have it.

Comment: @Jubobs minipages appear in the order you place them, like letters. So if you put two minipages in each row they will be numbered row wise

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right I hadn't thought about that. In that case, it would be best to define a custom environment for creating a row.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wouldn't that make the baseline misalignment even worse?

Comment: @Jubobs or (what I'd do probably) is not think of it row wise at all, just put each eqn in a minipage of say .45\textwidth and set them one after the other and leave the paragraph breaker to split them in to rows

Comment: @kmacinnis you really want the equation numbers on each row to be aligned, hang on I'll post some code in an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's another proposal using my [`tasks`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setlength\parindent{0in}

\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newlength{\spacer}
\setlength{\spacer}{1in}

\begin{document}

\section{More Practice With Trig Identities}

Establish each identity.
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk.](2)
  \task $(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)(\sec\theta-\tan\theta)=1$
  \task $\dfrac{1-\sin\theta}{1+\sin\theta} = (\sec\theta-\tan\theta)^2 $
    \vspace{\spacer}
  \task $\tan^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\cot^2\theta\sin^2\theta=1 $
  \task $\sec^4\theta - \sec^2\theta= \tan^4\theta + \tan^2\theta $
    \vspace{\spacer}
  \task $\sec\theta-\tan\theta=\dfrac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin\theta} $ 
  \task $3\sin^2\theta+4\cos^2\theta=\cos^2\theta+3 $
    \vspace{\spacer}
  \task $1-\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = \cos\theta $ 
  \task $\cos^2\theta(1+\tan^2\theta)=1$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for also getting rid of the unneeded `\left` and `\right` directives. :-)

Comment: exsheets looks great! I'm going to check it out.

Comment: @Jubobs this answer doesn't actually use it, though, but only its sub-package `tasks`...

Comment: Wow-- `exsheets` (and `tasks`), where have you been all my life?!  After reviewing the documentation, it's even better-- I can set `after-item-skip` instead of doing the \spacer nonsense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Although I, too, would opt for `exsheets`, this is a solution that exploits the `\question` command of the `exam` class you're using already and `minipage`s.

You must use, in this case, the new defined environment `myquestion`

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\footer{}{}{}
\parindent=0in
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\newlength{\spacer}
\setlength{\spacer}{0.5in}

\newenvironment{myquestion}{%
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
  \question
}{%
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace{\spacer}
}

\begin{document}

\section{More Practice With Trig Identities}
Establish each identity.

\raggedright

\begin{questions}
\begin{myquestion}
  \((\sec\theta+\tan\theta)(\sec\theta-\tan\theta)=1\)
\end{myquestion}
\begin{myquestion}
  \(\dfrac{1-\sin\theta}{1+\sin\theta} = (\sec\theta-\tan\theta)^2\)
\end{myquestion}
\begin{myquestion}
  \(\tan^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\cot^2\theta\sin^2\theta=1\)
\end{myquestion}
\begin{myquestion}
  \(\sec^4\theta - \sec^2\theta= \tan^4\theta + \tan^2\theta\)
\end{myquestion}
\begin{myquestion}
  \(\sec\theta-\tan\theta=\dfrac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin\theta}\)
\end{myquestion}
\begin{myquestion}
  \(3\sin^2\theta+4\cos^2\theta=\cos^2\theta+3\)
\end{myquestion}
\begin{myquestion}
  \(1-\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = \cos\theta\)
\end{myquestion}
\begin{myquestion}
  \(\cos^2\theta(1+\tan^2\theta)=1\)
\end{myquestion}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to tables, just set the whole thing as a paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{kpfonts}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\footer{}{}{}
\parindent=0in
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\large\bfseries\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\section{More Practice With Trig Identities}
Establish each identity.

\raggedright
\setlength\baselineskip{1in plus \fill}

\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\left(\sec\theta+\tan\theta\right)\left(\sec\theta-\tan\theta\right)=1
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{1-\sin\theta}{1+\sin\theta} = \left(\sec\theta-\tan\theta\right)^2
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\tan^2\theta\cos^2\theta+\cot^2\theta\sin^2\theta=1
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\sec^4\theta - \sec^2\theta= \tan^4\theta + \tan^2\theta
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\sec\theta-\tan\theta=\dfrac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin\theta}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
3\sin^2\theta+4\cos^2\theta=\cos^2\theta+3
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
1-\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{1+\cos\theta} = \cos\theta 
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\cos^2\theta\left(1+\tan^2\theta\right)=1
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```