# Format a enumerate environment like a tabular

Tags: tables, lists

**NOTE: The point is not to modify the enumerate environment. I need to convert it to the tabular like environment automatically.**

I would like to format an `enumerate` environment of 4 items

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Fist point
\item Second point
\item Third point
\item Fourth point
\end{enumerate}
```

like a tabular environment. The output should be similar to the output of

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}rr@{}}
a) Fist point  & b) Second point \\
c) Third point & d) Fourth point \\
\end{tabular}
```

My first thought was to use `inline` lists, but this would not assure that items b) and d) are aligned.

I'm sorry for not having yet a `MWE`, but I am looking more for ideas to start playing with that a full answer. I will edit the question when I have something more concrete.

Comment: But your `tabular` won't compile because it doesn't include the alignment specifiers on the first line. E.g. `\begin{tabular}{ll}`.

Comment: I think a very similar question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1398225/2682729 using the multicols package.

Comment: Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128653/arranging-exercises-row-wise-on-the-page

Comment: @varun The difference is that in my case the order goes from left to right and top to botom; which is different from the other answer.

Comment: You also can take a look at [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210032/lists-shaped-like-tables/210075#210075], which demonstrates the `tasks` solution, already mentioned by @Clemens, and a solution based on the `shortlst` package.

Comment: see David Carlisle's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67966/enumerate-in-multicols you can redefine `enumerate` to be `horizlist`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{.49\textwidth}p{.49\textwidth}}%%change the number as required
a) First point  & b) Second point \\
c) Third point & d) Fourth point \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Improved version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{newenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}\begin{tabular}{p{.49\textwidth}p{.49\textwidth}}
 }{\end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}

\begin{newenumerate}
\item First point &
\item Second point\\
\item Third point&
\item Fourth point
\end{newenumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the point is not to modify the enumerate environment. I need to convert it to the tabular like environment automatically.

Comment: @TeXtnik Does the improved version suit your needs?